# C# Response.Write CSV file not splits the cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, response.write

I have this code:

```
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Clients.csv");
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
    context.Response.Buffer = false;

    foreach (var c in clients)
    {
        context.Response.Output.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", c.FirstName, c.LastName));
    }
```

The downloaded file looks fine, except the fact that all row cells is merged into one cell.
I must use the Response as BinaryWrite because of Hebrew and Japan characters in the csv/xls content.
How to write splitted cells csv/xls file with binary write?

Answer (score 0):

To [quote Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Application_support):

> Microsoft Excel will open .csv files, but depending on the system's
>   regional settings, **it may expect a semicolon as a separator** instead of
>   a comma, since in some languages the comma is used as the decimal
>   separator.

So although it is called Comma Separated Values, I do think you should give it a try using semicolons instead of commas.

I.e. use:

```
context.Response.Output.WriteLine(
    string.Format("{0};{1}", c.FirstName, c.LastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to sanitize your strings by wrapping the string with double quotes when there is any comma, the way excel does it while saving your csv file.